# What does the "__cplusplus" macro expand to?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

- What does the C++ macro `__cplusplus` contain and expand to?
- Does the macro `__cplusplus` always, even in oldest C++ implementation, contain and expand to a *numeric* value?
- Is it safe to use `#if __cplusplus`
  or should we use instead of that `#ifdef __cplusplus`?

---

### Conclusion <sup>(added later)</sup>

From comments and accepted answer:

- `__cplusplus` expands to a number representing the standard's version, except pre-standard C++ in the early 90s (which simply expanded to `1`).
- Yes, even in oldest C++ implementation (expands to a numeric value).
- No, `#ifdef` should be used when header is shared with C-language (because some C-compilers will warn when `#if` checks undefined macro).

Comment: For C, it should be undefined (unless you're dealing with a malicious compiler writer); for C++, it should be defined, possibly to a useful value, but at least defined.  If you want to work with 'even the oldest C++ implementations', do not assume anything more than "it is defined".

Comment: What do you consider to be "the oldest C++ implementation"?  C++98?  Older?  How much older?

Comment: The question was originally tagged with C, and the title included 'C' rather than C++.  The tags were predominantly C++ tags, though.  However, **[C11 §6.10.8 Predefined macro names ¶3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.8)** says: _The implementation shall not predefine the macro `__cplusplus`, nor shall it define it
in any standard header._  The C99 standard says essentially the same, in a slightly different section.  The C90 standard was silent on the issue.

Comment: since an undefined macro will expand to false/zero we just need __cplusplus evaluate to "true" when defined so we can short up code and conditions

Comment: For a long time g++ defined it as 1. #ifdef is the traditional way to test, some compilers will warn if you use #if instead.

Comment: was not aware g++ may count undefined as 1 - in which version did that stop?

Comment: @Top-Master g++ started defining __cplusplus to 199711L in gcc-4.7. It never expanded undefined macros as 1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it always does expand to numeric value and its meaning is the version of C++ standard that is being used. According to cppreference [page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace), `__cplusplus` macro should expand to:

> - 199711L (until C++11),
> - 201103L (C++11),
> - 201402L (C++14),
> - 201703L (C++17),
> - 202002L (C++20)

The difference between `#if` and `#ifdef` directives is that `#ifdef` should be used to check whether given macro has been defined to allow a section of code to be compiled.

On the other hand `#if` (`#else`, `#elif`) directives can be used to check whether specified condition is met (just like typical if-condition).

Comment: are you even sure for oldest C++ version ?

Comment: Yes, the C++98 standard explicitly says so — I checked in my copy.

Comment: Note that for a long time, `__cplusplus` in some compilers simply expanded to `1`.

Comment: Of course, if you were experimenting with pre-standard c++ in the early 90s, that standard didn't exist, just as now you can experiment with c++20. If you are still using such a compiler all bets are off, but then your sanity must be questioned. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`__cplusplus` is required to be defined by the C++ standard. For C++11 or higher `__cplusplus > 199711L` should hold `true`.

---

> Does the macro __cplusplus always, even in oldest C++ implementation,
>   contain and expand to a numeric value?

Yes it does.

---

[19.8](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.predefined#:__cplusplus) C++11

> ```
> __cplusplus
> ```
>
> The integer literal 201703L. [ Note: It is intended that future
>   versions of this International Standard will replace the value of this
>   macro with a greater value. — end note  ]

---

[C++98](http://www.lirmm.fr/~ducour/Doc-objets/ISO+IEC+14882-1998.pdf)

> `__cplusplus` The  name
>   _ 
>   _cplusplus is  defined  to  the  value 199711L when  compiling  a  C
>   ++ translation unit. 143)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `__cplusplus` macro has the value `199711` in MS Visual Studio 2022, regardless of the specified C++ standard. Use `_MSVC_LANG` instead. See [VS comment](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/msvc-incorrectly-defines-cplusplus/139261).

This seems to work:

```
#if defined(_MSVC_LANG)  // MS compiler has different __cplusplus value.
#   if _MSVC_LANG < 201703
#       error Please compile for C++17 or higher
#   endif
#else  // All other compilers.
#   if __cplusplus < 201703
#       error Please compile for C++17 or higher
#   endif
#endif
```

Comment: You can just use `#if __cplusplus < 201703` nowadays, as your link states! The issue was resolved back in 2018.  VS2019 and VS2022 have full C++17 support, but VS2017 was still a bit iffy.

Comment: No, __cplusplus has the value 199711 in MS Visual Studio 2022 with C++17.