# Strange thing with versions

Tags: c++

I have a really strange thing: I have g++ 10.3.0 (checked in terminal with `g++ --version`), but `__cplusplus` is showing 201402L date... How is this possible? I know 10.3.0 release were patched in april of 2021

Comment: You're confusing the compiler version with the *language* version in effect.

Comment: Help guys, how to install c++20 standard compiler? (I tried mingw, but only 17 stardard is available). Maybe I'm just a "genius" and blind? Please, could u share the link or repository to gcc, something. Thanks!

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html <-- This will help you. It lists when the GCC has started supporting which feature of the standard. Be mindful that this is about the GCC. Mingw may have a different chart.

Answer (score 3):

The __cplusplus macro does not reflect the version of your compiler, but the version of the C++ standard you are using.

For further information, you may also look at [What does the "__cplusplus" macro expand to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49915424/what-does-the-cplusplus-macro-expand-to)